# Strip Word document for formatting but not images?

Tags: html, ms-word

I need to add a bunch of word documents to a wiki but want to clean up the resulting html so ideally I have text and image tags... Anyone up for a challenge? :o)

It's ok if the solution involves using a text editor and doing some "gymnastics" on it.

Answer (score 2):

There are tools that perform much of this cleaning for you, like [here](http://wordoff.org/) or [here](http://www.textism.com/wordcleaner/) and Dreamweaver includes such a tool as well.

I don't know what these tools do with images though...  If you choose a more DIY route, [this](http://www.1stclassmedia.co.uk/developers/clean-ms-word-formatting.php) can help you I think.

Comment: The Textism tool seems to work (the first one strips the image tags), though it's payed service when file size is above 20 kB.

The JavaScript might also be of assistance :o)

Answer (score 1):

I would copy the text out of Word and paste it into Notepad and then manually enter my images into the Wiki document.

Comment: This is not a valid solution. With hundres of documents loaded with pictures - manual inserts is a no go. It's ok to do some advanced textediting or maybe an application using e.g. VSTO, running through the documents saving as filtered html and correcting the image links to fit the wiki file structure...

Answer (score 1):

Hi I've worked a little with Open XML.

You can just either cycle through the word document checking each paragraph and converting each element into literalcontrols. Or you can also use LINQ to filter specific nodesets. You could also just treat your word file as an XML nodeset and navigate with XPath, LINQ to XML, DOM.

Just try downloading the Open XML toolset with SDK and start looking inside of your documents.